# Could not open input file

Tags: laravel, cmd

Estoy comenzando en laravel pero me sale el error `Could not open input file:` estoy en windows, lo probé como administrador, en xampp, pero continua el error, en ambos casos dentro de la carpeta laravel y nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: al parecer nunca entras dentro de las carpeta de los proyectos que creaste. Además para ejecutar los comandos de Laravel es: `php artisan command`. Debes hacer `cd tu path/proyecto` y luego sí ejecutar los comandos.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes diferentes formas de crear un proyecto nuevo...

Te recomiendo una: vía composer, en su web oficial puedes descargarte el instalador para windows (https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Después podrás ejecutar:

```
 
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

y el comando que estabas tratando de hacer por último, para servir la aplicación en http://localhost:8000

```
php artisan serve
```

La documentación oficial con más detalles: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation

Si te fallan estos comandos o tienes algún otro problema, te animo a volver a preguntar. Suerte.

Comment: en cada una de las carpetas la cree de esa forma, y persiste lo mismo, tambien usé **laravel new blog**